Can I create a wrapper filter around Ignite WebSessionFilter to use own session id for session replication?
I am using Ignite WebSessionFilter for the session replication/synchronization.
Looking at the code, the filter is using the http session id or jsessionId to cache the session.
But, our application not working correctly with these ids, because the session id/cookie is not set in the response by ignite web filter, the cookie can't shared between webapps in same tomcat instance.
Hazelcast-wm provides different session clustering using its own cookie 'hazelcast.sessionid'.
Can i achieve similar behavior with Ignite web filter??
Can we wrap methods to create own session id that can be used by ignite web session filter??
